# jbpm 7.40 (docker) exits with errors

Tags: docker, jbpm

I have followed the instructions to install and start jbpm 7.40 with docker desktop (2.3.0.3.)

After starting the container it exits with several errors messsages.

Examples of warnings and errors:

```
18:34:46,802 WARN [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Read timed out
```

```
18:34:30,335 WARN [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Read timed out
```

```
18:33:49,956 WARN [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYRS0018: Explicit usage of Jackson annotation in a JAX-RS deployment; the system will disable JSON-B processing for the current deployment. Consider setting the 'resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB' property to 'false' to restore JSON-B.
```

```
18:35:28,838 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0043: Deployment unit processor org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.BeanValidationFactoryDeployer@4ded5bd0 unexpectedly threw an exception during undeploy phase POST_MODULE of deployment "jbpm-casemgmt.war": org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000229: Contextual reference of ValidatorFactoryBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidatorFactoryBean_default] is not valid after container jbpm-casemgmt.war shutdown

at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:85)

at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)

at org.hibernate.validator@6.0.18.Final//org.hibernate.validator.AutoCloseable$HibernateValidatorFactory$ValidatorFactory$917720531$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.close(Unknown Source)

at org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation@19.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.LazyValidatorFactory.close(LazyValidatorFactory.java:134)

at org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation@19.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.undeploy(BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.java:130)

at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.safeUndeploy(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:245)

at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.stop(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:238)

at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.stopService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1795)

at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1764)

at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

```
18:35:29,974 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment jbpm-casemgmt.war (runtime-name: jbpm-casemgmt.war) in 2154ms

18:35:30,064 INFO [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.ControllerConnectRunnable] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Connected to controller, quiting connector thread

18:35:30,685 INFO [org.dashbuilder.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-2) Core subsystems initialized

18:35:31,248 INFO [org.eclipse.jgit.internal.ketch.KetchSystem] (MSC service thread 1-2) Using 5 threads

18:35:32,819 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@6478f099 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:523)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1518)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1472)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1445)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1319)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:876)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)

at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:448)

at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:401)

at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

```
18:35:32,820 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@6478f099 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing the startup command `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name jbpm-server-full jboss/jbpm-server-full:7.40.0.Final` I can verify the first three of your mentioned warning messages. But as far as I can see they are not relevant. Access to http://localhost:8080/business-central is possible after some seconds of loading time.

Check if [granting](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#resources) at least 6 GB memory and 4 cores helps.